# bash text processing and error message

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

for example I have this script that kills firefox

```
ps x | grep firefox | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'| xargs kill -9
```

but when there is no firefox running it spits out:

```
Usage:
  kill pid ...              Send SIGTERM to every process listed.
  kill signal pid ...       Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -s signal pid ...    Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -l                   List all signal names.
  kill -L                   List all signal names in a nice table.
  kill -l signal            Convert between signal numbers and names.
```

What is the easiest way to display error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command for detecting Firefox processes is horrible, it also includes processes with "firefox" in their command line (e.g. directory name). Use `pidof firefox` instead.

You can first save the PIDs, check for whether it's (non)empty and adjust the behavior:

```
pids=$(pidof firefox)
if [ -n "$pids" ]; then
    kill -9 $pids
else
    echo "No Firefox processes found"
fi
```

Or use `killall` instead if you do not need an error message:

```
killall firefox
```